# Firebase/Google analytics share with Firebase features

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

The firebase console under Settings -> Integrations -> Google Analytics has a Data Sharing section with a bunch of check boxes, one of which is:

> **Share Analytics data with all Firebase features (Recommended)**:
>   Including Crashlytics, Predictions, A/B Testing, Remote Config, Cloud
>   Messaging, and In-App Messaging

The word "Share" is confusing to me. Does this mean there's an underlying set of data that is collected by default and unless I check this box, these other firebase features won't have access to that data?

If I don't select this option will data still be collected? Will data be available to any part of my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable <kbd>Share Analytics data with all Firebase features</kbd> then the analytics data in your Firebase project is only available within the analytics panel, and won't be used in the other Firebase products.

So if you uncheck the box, you won't be able to (for example) send targeted notifications (using Cloud Messaging or In-App Messaging) based on analytics data, or run predictions of future user behavior. But you will be able to see the analytics data in the Firebase console, and you can allow the data to be exported to BigQuery.